# Kafka on AWS ECS, how to handle advertised.host without known instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, apache-kafka, amazon-ecs

I'm trying to get Kafka running on an AWS ECS container. I have this setup already / working fine on my local docker environment, using the `spotify/kafka` [image](https://github.com/spotify/docker-kafka)

To get this working locally, I needed to ensure the [ADVERTISED_HOST environment variable was set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43103167/failed-to-resolve-kafka9092-name-or-service-not-known-docker-php-rdkafka). `ADVERTISED_HOST` needed to be set as the containers external IP, otherwise when I try to connect it was just giving me `connection refused`.

My local `docker-compose.yaml` has this for the kafka container:

```
  kafka:
    image: spotify/kafka
    hostname: kafka
    environment:
    - ADVERTISED_HOST=192.168.0.70
    - ADVERTISED_PORT=9092
    ports:
    - "9092:9092"
    - "2181:2181"
    restart: always
```

Now the problem is, I don't know what the IP is going to be, as I dont know which instance this will run on. So how do I set that environment variable?

Comment: Have you tried `0.0.0.0`?

Comment: @kichik thanks for the response. Yes just tried that and didn't work, although I think it has to be the external IP (public or private would do), so that the Kafka brokers can connect to it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your entrypoint script will need to call the [EC2 Metadata Service](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html) on startup (in this case http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-hostname) to get the external-to-docker hostname and set that variable.

Sample:

```
[ec2-user ~]$ curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-hostname
ip-10-251-50-12.ec2.internal
```

Comment: Same has been documented here https://github.com/wurstmeister/kafka-docker/blob/master/README.md#advertised-hostname